# static plugin gstreamer on Android

Tags: android, plugins, gstreamer

I want create a custom plugin for GStreamer on Android. I want to know how i can cross compile a static custom plugin for Android and create the files *.a and *.la and add it to my project.

Thanking You.
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually don't have to create a custom plugin, unless it's something
that should be possible to be dropped into other applications. In that
case the only difference between static and dynamic plugins is build
system magic.

But if you only want to create a custom GstElement subclass for your
application, you can just do so without defining a new plugin. You would
just create the subclass in your application code and then call
gst_element_register() with the GType of your subclass and NULL as
plugin. It can then be used like any other GStreamer element.

Using gst_element_register() is also only necessary if you want to be
able to create an instance with gst_element_factory_make(). If you don't
need that, you can also just use the normal g_object_new() to create an
instance from the GType.

If you really want to create a static plugin, i.e. the .la and .a files necessary for that, you will have to write the plugin like a dynamic plugin. That is, use GST_PLUGIN_DEFINE() as usual and #define GST_PLUGIN_BUILD_STATIC while building with the Android toolchain.